# How do we get the border line between two similar colors using image processing or computer vision?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, pixel

Consider the below image. Here we have two colors, red and light red. I need to find the border between red and light red.
Here **the border pixels can have colors other than red and light red, that is it can include yellow color, black color etc. It means there is no guarantee that it only contains red or light red pixels.**
I want approximate border between these two colors given there may be pixel value variations(pixel may take yellow or black etc)

[Here is the example pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z49w7.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67120319/edit) the post to include your own effort into solving this problem. The latter preferably in code, this is called a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: you can see this [Tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d5c/tutorial_canny_detector.html) about Edge Detection.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Your image has precisely 3 colours - one column of extraneous  white junk down the left side, and the rest are either rgb(237,28,36) or rgb(244,128,121), so there are no yellows or blacks. So you can extremely simply split the two colours using any channel, e.g. the green and thresholding on any number greater than 28 and less than 128, for example.